# Can not retrieve only first value encountered when extracting values from column with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, set

**Currently my code looks like this:**

```
import pandas as pd

Version = {'2','4','6','8','10','12', 'more'}

data = {'Version':['some unwanted text 2 3 4 5', ' some more text 6 7 8 9 10', '12 more text 11 ']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def Version_finder(x):
    df_words = set(x.split(' '))
    extract_words =  Version.intersection(df_words)
    return ' '.join(extract_words)

df['New_Version'] = df.Version.apply(Version_finder)
```

**The output is:**

```
    Version                             New_Version
0   some unwanted text 2 3 4 5          4 2
1   some more text 6 7 8 9 10           6 10 more 8
2   12 more text 11                     12 more
```

**However the required output is:**

```
    Version                             New_Version
0   some unwanted text 2 3 4 5          2
1   some more text 6 7 8 9 10           more
2   12 more text 11                     12
```

**I need to only have 1 value returned in the 'New_Version' column. This needs to be the first value that occurs in the version column that is specified in the Set **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is not convert splitted values to set, because in set is not defined order, filter in list comprehension and last using `next` with `iter` for return first matched value if exist else `None`:

```
f = lambda x: next(iter([y for y in x.split() if y in Version]), None)
df['New_Version'] = df.Version.apply(f)
print (df)
                      Version New_Version
0  some unwanted text 2 3 4 5           2
1   some more text 6 7 8 9 10        more
2             12 more text 11          12
```